# Web Deployment Projects for VS2010 on build server failing with Error MSB4086

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, web-deployment-project

When I upgraded my Web Deployment Project from VS2008 to the VS2010 beta version, I was able to execute the build locally on my development box. However, when I tried to execute the build on our TeamCity build server, I began getting the following exception:

```
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v10.0\Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets(162, 37): 
error MSB4086: A numeric comparison was attempted on "$(_SourceWebProjectPath.Length)" 
that evaluates to "" instead of a number, in condition "'$(_SourceWebProjectPath)' != '' 
And $(_SourceWebProjectPath.Length) >= 4)".
```

I did install the Web Deployment Project addin on my build server and I did copy over the C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications directory on my development box to the C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\ directory on the build server. Note: My dev box is 64bit and the build server 32bit.

I can't figure out why this is behaving differently on the build server than on my dev machine. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: did you recreate your build task when you went to 2010 or are you using the same one from the 2008 WDP?

Comment: I am using the same one. I simply let VS2010 upgrade the WDProject after I installed WDP2010. Should I be recreating the build task and what exactly does that mean?

Comment: Did you get yout TeamCity autobuild + 2010 WebDeploymentProject working?  We are having problems too: our problem mirrors that of Asbjørn Ulsberg in the comments of this post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2010/05/26/visual-studio-2010-web-deployment-projects-rtw-available-now.aspx.  I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MSBuild 4` is not used during your build process (It is not installed and/or TeamCity is linked to MSBuild 3.5).

You have to make sure that `MSBuild 4` is the version used on your build server.

### Explanation (for information)

`Web Deployment Project 2010` use new feature of `MSBuild 4` like `Property function`. If a prior version of MSBuild is used the property function aren't evaluated and bad things happens.

If you look in the file `Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets` you should see this declaration :

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(SourceWebProject)' != ''">
  <_SourceWebProjectIndex>
    $([MSBuild]::Add(1, $(SourceWebProject.LastIndexof('|'))))
  </_SourceWebProjectIndex>
  <_SourceWebProjectPath>
    $(SourceWebProject.SubString($(_SourceWebProjectIndex)))
  </_SourceWebProjectPath>
  <_SourceWebProjectPathBeginWith Condition="'$(_SourceWebProjectPath)' != '' And ($(_SourceWebProjectPath.Length) &gt;= 4)">
    $(_SourceWebProjectPath.SubString(0,4))
  </_SourceWebProjectPathBeginWith>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The property `SourceWebProjectIndex` and `SourceWebProjectPath` use property functions, with MSBuild 3.5 they aren't evaluated, so the condition on `SourceWebProjectPathBeginWith` couldn't be evaluated either resulting in the error :

```
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v10.0\Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets(162, 37): 
error MSB4086: A numeric comparison was attempted on "$(_SourceWebProjectPath.Length)" 
that evaluates to "" instead of a number, in condition "'$(_SourceWebProjectPath)' != '' 
And $(_SourceWebProjectPath.Length) >= 4)".
```

Comment: Thanks much. I am still having other issues, but your help fixed that one.